# Auto printing orders from sql using django/laravel

Tags: django, laravel, pdf, printing

Is there any possibility to create app (django, laravel) - that would get data from database, table called orders and would automatically create pdf with data and download it?
Let's say, i've got 5 new orders, each for different address and different goods.
App should automatically create pdf and download for each of those 5 orders.

It could also be a react app getting orders from API.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In laravel DOMPDF [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) package can help you to create pdf with data. But do you want to give download option in app? And, where do you want to keep that file/

Comment: @Jayant The wouldn't be any options, the app should automatically check if there is any new order. If it is, then create pdf file, download it and save it, and print it. I've been trying to do it in django, however i stuck on creating and downloading only one file.